# sidebar extending to the 2nd page

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to use the CV template that is uploaded in here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/smart-twenty-seconds-cv

However, my CV is two pages but the sidebar in this template does not extend to the second page.

I would appreciate if someone could help me help fix this.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 1):

Add the command

```
\makeprofile
```

Everywhere in the second page's content...

It will recreate the same sidebar as in the first page... if you want to change things... please be more specific

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I add \makeprofile then the same sidebar as in the first page will be printed on the 2nd page as you also mentioned, however I want to add other things to the 2nd page sidebar, I know I will need to change the *.cls file but I don't know how.

Comment: You can describe or somehow draw the desired second page sidebar and I am going to help you fix it

Answer (score 0):

It's quite late but you can do it like this: add new information to your new sidebar in the second page. You can add the following lines to .tex file

```
\newpage %start a new page 
\makenewprofile %new page with sidebar
```

And in the .cls file add the following lines to have second side bar in the second page and add the information that you want to see in the second sidebar of your cv (e.g name(it's my naming, you can change it to Hobbies, courses, anything else in the formula)).

```
\newcommand{\makenewprofile}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=8.25cm, 
               minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{textblock}{6}(0.3, 0.2)
        
    %------------------------------------------------

    %{\normalsize\color{mainblue}\cvname}

    %-------------------------------------------
    \vspace{4mm}
    %-------------------------------------------
    \profilesection{name}\\
    
    \name{whatever you want to add to this part}\\          
    \nametext
    \scriptsize

    %------------------------------------------------
        
\end{textblock}
}
```

Comment: Can you should the effect of this?

Comment: With this \makenewprofile you can create second page with new side bar that you can add extra information in it. and if you want more pages with different sidebar you can extend it like \makenewnewprofile (it's only a name) in twentysecond cv template.

Comment: Can you make small document that demonstrates this and add its output?

Comment: I updated my comment and my script for modifying the latex file.