# How to extend the sidebar in the second page using Simple Hipster CV template?

Tags: templates, overleaf, cv, sidebar

I am using the [Simple Hipster CV template](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/simple-hipster-cv/cnpkkjdkyhhw) and I am having problems addind a new page. This template has a grey sidebar (which I really like) but I cannot extend it to a second page. I would like to have it completely (from the beginning to the end, margins completed), as it appears in the first page.

[image: image 1]

I have found some [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375753/sidebar-extending-to-the-2nd-page) about adding sidebars to second pages, but it doesn't work with this template (or at least, I don't know how to do it).

Could anyone help me, please?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: a]

This is the complete template.

Added `\renewcommand{\paracolbackgroundoptions}{%`  at the beginning and changed the last part to use the second page after `\section*{Talks}`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[lighthipster]{simplehipstercv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[default]{raleway}
\usepackage[margin=1cm, a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[margin=1cm, a4paper]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\paracolbackgroundoptions}{% Added<<<< <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \backgroundcolor{c[0](28pt,10.5pt)(0.5\columnsep,4pt)}[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}
    \backgroundcolor{c[1](0.5\columnsep,4pt)(4pt,4pt)}[rgb]{1,1,1}
    \backgroundcolor{C[0](10000pt,10000pt)(0.5\columnsep,10000pt)}[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}
    \backgroundcolor{C[1](0.5\columnsep,10000pt)(10000pt,10000pt)}[rgb]{1,1,1}
}


%------------------------------------------------------------------ Variablen

\newlength{\rightcolwidth}
\newlength{\leftcolwidth}
\setlength{\leftcolwidth}{0.23\textwidth}
\setlength{\rightcolwidth}{0.75\textwidth}

%------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{New Simple CV}
\author{\LaTeX{} Ninja}
\date{June 2019}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\section*{Start}

\simpleheader{headercolour}{Jack}{Sparrow}{Captain}{white}

%------------------------------------------------

% this has to be here so the paracols starts..
\subsection*{}
\vspace{4em}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}
\columnratio{0.23}[0.75]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\hbadness5000
\paracolbackgroundoptions

\footnotesize
{\setasidefontcolour
\flushright
\begin{center}
    \roundpic{jack.jpg}
\end{center}

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{About me}\\[0.5em]

{\footnotesize
\lorem\lorem\lorem}
\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{personal} \\[0.5em]
Jack Sparrow

nationality: English 

1690

\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Areas of specialization} \\[0.5em]

Privateering ~•~ Bucaneering ~•~ Parler ~•~ Rum

\bigskip

\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Interests}\\[0.5em]

\lorem
\bigskip

\bg{cvgreen}{white}{Interests}\\[0.5em]

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\texttt{R} ~/~ \texttt{Android} ~/~ \texttt{Linux}

\vspace{4em}

\infobubble{\faAt}{cvgreen}{white}{jack@sparrow.org}
\infobubble{\faTwitter}{cvgreen}{white}{@sparrow}
\infobubble{\faFacebook}{cvgreen}{white}{Jack Sparrow}
\infobubble{\faGithub}{cvgreen}{white}{sparrow}

\phantom{turn the page}

\phantom{turn the page}
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\switchcolumn

\small
\section*{Short Resumé}

\begin{tabular}{r| p{0.5\textwidth} c}
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back.\lorem\lorem\lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2016--2017}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{Found a secret treasure, lost the ship. \lorem\lorem}{medal.jpeg}
\end{tabular}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
\section*{Degrees}
\begin{tabular}{r p{0.6\textwidth} c}
    \cvdegree{1710}{Captain}{Certified}{Tortuga Uni \color{headerblue}}{}{disney.png} \\
    \cvdegree{1715}{Bucaneering}{M.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg} \\
    \cvdegree{1720}{Bucaneering}{B.A.}{London \color{headerblue}}{}{medal.jpeg}
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Programming}
\begin{tabular}{r @{\hspace{0.5em}}l}
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{html, css} &  \barrule{0.4}{0.5em}{cvpurple}\\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{\LaTeX} & \barrule{0.55}{0.5em}{cvgreen} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{python} & \barrule{0.5}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{R} & \barrule{0.25}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
     \bg{skilllabelcolour}{iconcolour}{javascript} & \barrule{0.1}{0.5em}{cvpurple} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\section*{Curriculum}
\begin{tabular}{r| p{0.5\textwidth} c}
    \cvevent{2018--2021}{Captain of the Black Pearl}{Lead}{East Indies \color{cvred}}{Finally got the goddamn ship back. \lorem}{disney.png} \\
    \cvevent{2019}{Freelance Pirate}{Bucaneering}{Tortuga \color{cvred}}{This and that. The usual, aye?  \lorem}{medal.jpeg} \\
\end{tabular}
\vspace{3em}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Certificates \& Grants}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.55\textwidth}}
    1708 & Captain's Certificates \\
    1710 & Travel grant \\
    1715--1716 & Grant from the Pirate's Company
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\section*{Languages}
\begin{tabular}{l | ll}
\textbf{English} & C2 & {\phantom{x}\footnotesize mother tongue} \\
\textbf{French} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{3}{black!30}{1}{\tiny} \\
\textbf{Spanish} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{1}{black!30}{3}{\tiny} \\
\textbf{Italian} & C2 & \pictofraction{\faCircle}{cvgreen}{3}{black!30}{1}{\tiny}
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
\section*{Publications}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.7\textwidth}}
    1729 & \emph{How I almost got killed by Lady Swan}, Tortuga Printing Press. \\
    1720 & ``Privateering for Beginners'', in: \emph{The Pragmatic Pirate} (1/1720).
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\section*{Talks}
\begin{tabular}{>{\footnotesize\bfseries}r >{\footnotesize}p{0.6\textwidth}}
    Nov. 1726 & ``How I lost my ship (\& and how to get it back)'', at: \emph{Annual Pirate's Conference} in Tortuga, Nov. 1726.
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

%***************************************************** changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\end{paracol}

\newpage
\begin{paracol}{2}
\hbadness5000
    
\paracolbackgroundoptions
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\switchcolumn
\section*{Other stuff}

\lorem

\lorem 

\lorem 
\vfill

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FINAL FOOTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\rightcolwidth}
    \begin{center}\fontfamily{\sfdefault}\selectfont \color{black!70}
    {\small Jack Sparrow \icon{\faEnvelopeO}{cvgreen}{} The Black Pearl \icon{\faMapMarker}{cvgreen}{} Tortuga \icon{\faPhone}{cvgreen}{} 0099/333 5647380 \newline\icon{\faAt}{cvgreen}{} \protect\url{jack@sparrow.com}
    }
    \end{center}
\end{minipage}

\clearpage

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is exactly what I wanted!!!